# Windows 10 IPv6 token support

Tags: networking, powershell, ipv6, windows-10

I am looking for the Windows 10 equivalent of [Linux's IPv6 token support](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4554/gbvsf/index.html).

When I do a `Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily ipv6` (PowerShell) on Windows I get output akin to this:

```
IPAddress         : <REDACTED>
InterfaceIndex    : 15
InterfaceAlias    : Ethernet
AddressFamily     : IPv6
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 128
PrefixOrigin      : Dhcp
SuffixOrigin      : Dhcp
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : 11:51:45
PreferredLifetime : 11:51:45
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore
```

Notice the [`PrefixOrigin`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.prefixorigin) and [`SuffixOrigin`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.suffixorigin).

Is there a way in Windows to set a fixed SuffixOrigin without locking down the Prefix?

Comment: I _think_ you're looking for ` 
Set-NetIPv6Protocol -RandomizeIdentifiers Disabled`

Comment: @JacobEvans Thanks, but that is to disable the Temporary addresses that Windows uses when getting an address via SLAAC. Those are the Privacy Extensions: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e36e82e9-1911-4f4d-91a2-c62f6e04c9c1/ipv6-turn-off-privacy-extensions-temporary-addresses-for-certain-prefixes-ie-ula-in-win-10?forum=win10itpronetworking